# dynamodb query with filters returns no items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

| id(string) | message(string) | created(number) | completed(boolean) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Instruction | 1686731293161 | - |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 129 | Instruction | 1686821275413 | false |

`Partition key`: message
`Sort key`: created
`Projected keys`: All

In summary for the table:

- some entries does not have message and completed attributes
- even though message is used as partition key in GSI, this is ok for my use case

I tried to query using aws-sdk dynamodb client with this params:

```
  TableName: "test-idStatus",
  IndexName: "messageCreatedIndex",
  KeyConditionExpression: "#message = :message and #created BETWEEN :createdfrom AND :createdto",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#message": "message",
    "#created": "created",
    "#completed": "completed",
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":messageFunction": "Instruction",
    ":createdfrom": 1686817506000, // 2023-June-15 08:25
    ":createdto": 1686821106000,   // 2023-June-15 09:25
    ":completed": "false",
  },
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  Limit: 5,
  Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
  FilterExpression: "#completed = :completed",
}
```

This returned entries

But when I changed the `ExpressionAttributeValues` of:
`createdfrom`:  1686731286000 (2023-June-14 08:25) 
This did not return any entries (but returns a LastEvaluatedKey).
Which is weird since June-15 returned entries which is just a subset of June-14 to June-15 entries

I also tried to replicate this in the AWS console dynamoDB,
The same thing happened.

Then I also tried removing `ScanIndexForward`, now it returned entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that you set a FilterExpression and a Limit. What happens now is that DynamoDB reads 5 items as that is your Limit and then applies your filter to those 5 items but none match the expression so you get an empty response.

Changing the date is simply changing the 5 items read and it's just luck that they match your filter. The same goes for changing the scan direction, you're just changing the first 5 items.